# How do you pass kwargs to a boost-python wrapped function?

Tags: boost-python, keyword-argument

I have a python function with this signature:

```
def post_message(self, message, *args, **kwargs):
```

I would like to call the function from c++ and pass to it some kwargs. Calling the function is not the problem. Knowing how to pass the kwargs is. Here is a non-working paraphrased sample:

```
std::string message("aMessage");
boost::python::list arguments;
arguments.append("1");

boost::python::dict options;
options["source"] = "cpp";

boost::python::object python_func = get_python_func_of_wrapped_object()
python_func(message, arguments, options)
```

When I exercise this code, in pdb I get (which is not what I would like):

```
messsage = aMessage
args = (['1'], {'source': 'cpp'})
kwargs = {}
```

How do you pass the *options* in my example in the **kwargs dictionary ?

I have seen one [post](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-python-call-python-function-with-kwargs-from-c-td2703011.html) suggesting to use the **options syntax (how cool is this!):

```
python_func(message, arguments, **options)
```

Unfortunately, this results in

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class boost::python::detail::kwds_proxy
```

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some investigation, it turns out that the object function call operator is overridden for two arguments of type **`args_proxy`** and **`kwds_proxy`**. So you have to use this specific call style of two arguments.

`args_proxy` and `kwds_proxy` are generated by the * overloads. This is really nice.

Additionally, the first argument must be a tuple type so that the python interpreter correctly handles the *args argument.

The resulting example works:

```
boost::python::list arguments;
arguments.append("aMessage");
arguments.append("1");

boost::python::dict options;
options["source"] = "cpp";

boost::python::object python_func = get_python_func_of_wrapped_object()
python_func(*boost::python::tuple(arguments), **options)
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the * and ** overloads, one of those tiny details which make boost::python admirable.

Comment: Note that even when only kwargs are used, the tuple as first argument is needed. It can be empty, though: `python_func(*boost::python::tuple(), **options)`.