# Calling a python constructor with named argument from C++

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I want to create a Thread instance from C++, with `target=entity` passed into the constructor, where `entity` is a `boost::python::object`, as this Python code is showing:

```
pythread = Thread(target=entity)
```

I saw [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612261/how-can-i-specify-the-value-of-a-named-argument-in-boost-python) and came up with this code. It throws an unhandled exception on the line `object pythread = ...`. How can I do this?

```
void start(boost::python::object entity){
    using namespace boost::python;
    object main_module = import("__main__");
    object global = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    exec("from threading import Thread", global, global);

    dict kw;
    kw["target"] = entity.attr("start");

    object pythread = main_module.attr("Thread").attr("__init__"); //exception here

    PyObject* c_retval = PyObject_Call(pythread.ptr(), NULL, kw.ptr());

    object t = object(handle<>(c_retval));
    t.attr("start")();
}
```

Edit: Since Python's `Thread` object is defined as `Thread(group=None, target=None, ...)`, the following code should work to pass in the correct argument:

```
object pythread = main_module.attr("Thread")(object(),entity.attr("start"));
```

However, passing `entity.attr("Start")` results in an error (no to_python converter). That is a problem for another SO post.

Comment: You could try `.def` instead of `.attr`

Comment: Where? I thought def was used to expose functions - entity.start definitely does already exist, or it would print an error in the python console (which it doesn't). `object::def` does not return `object`.