# Boost::Python: no converter found for C++ type: boost::python::detail::kwds_proxy

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

We are trying to embed several Python procedures in our C++ code using and it fails with an error

> TypeError: No to_python (by_value) converter found for C++ type: boost::python::detail::kwds_proxy

We honestly studied all the examples we managed to find over the network ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500755/how-do-you-pass-kwargs-to-a-boost-python-wrapped-function) and [this](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.c++/month=20091201)), but still we have no any clear solution for **passing the** ****kwargs** variable **from C++ to Python**. This failure seems to be very rare.

Python function we are trying to call recieves a string value and a dictionary:

```
from ipalib import api
user_kw = dict(givenname=u'Test', sn=u'User')
api.Command.user_add.(u'Pythonist', **user_kw)
```

This is its C++ implementation:

```
//Importing modules
bp::import("__main__");
ipalib = bp::import("ipalib");
ipalib_namespace = ipalib.attr("__dict__");
api = ipalib.attr("api");

... //Starting Python environment

//Construct args
std::string name = "Pythonist";
bp::dict new_user;
new_user["givenname"] = "Test";
new_user["sn"] = "User";

//Calling the function
bp::object user_add_wrapper = api.attr("Command").attr("user_add");
user_add_wrapper(name, new_user);
```

And on the last line Boost throws an exception. What are we doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user_add_wrapper(name, new_user)` tries to pass `new_user` as a dictionary to `user_add_wrapper()`, rather than passing the unpacked contents of `new_user`.  The `new_user` dictionary needs to be unpacked.  Additionally, calling the `python::object` with an unpacked dictionary requires the first argument to be an unpacked `boost::python::tuple`.  To account for these requirements, invoke `user_add_wrapper()` as follows:

```cpp
user_add_wrapper(*bp::make_tuple(name), **new_user);
```

This behavior is part of the seamless interoperability provided by Boost.Python, but it is rather obscure and I only recall noticing it mentioned indirectly in the [change log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/news.html) rather than the tutorial or reference.

---

Below is a complete minimal example.  Given `example.py`:

```python
def user_add(name, givenname, sn):
    print locals()
```

The following program invokes `user_add()` by unpacking a dictionary:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main()
{
  Py_Initialize(); // Start interpreter.

  // Create the __main__ module.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::object main = python::import("__main__");
  python::object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");

  try
  {
    python::object example = python::import("example");
    python::object example_namespace = example.attr("__dict__");

    // Construct args.
    std::string name = "Pythonist";
    python::dict new_user;
    new_user["givenname"] = "Test";
    new_user["sn"] = "User";

    // Invoke user_add by unpacking the new_user dictionary.
    example_namespace["user_add"](*python::make_tuple(name), **new_user);
  }
  catch (const python::error_already_set&)
  {
    PyErr_Print();
  }
}
```

And produces the following output:

```
{'givenname': 'Test', 'sn': 'User', 'name': 'Pythonist'}
```

Comment: Thank you for a great help! Your example gave us everything we need. The only thing we had to do is filling both the dictionary and tuple with std::wstring values (for instance, new_user["givenname"]=std::wstring(L"Test")).

Comment: For future readers who only want to pass the kwargs without a "normal" argument before, you can use an empty tuple like this: `wrapped_function(*boost::python::tuple(), **args)`